# How to set absolute position of image inside a div

Tags: html, css

I am trying (without success) to set the absolute position of a little close image inside a div. The image should appear at the left side of the div whatever the content of the div. The content is a text label with a max length = 8 characters
Problem : the position of the image depends of the length of the text, and it should not be the case !  [demo jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnopn1tL/)
I would like the position of the image is still the same if the text is "Er" and if the text is "erica"

```
div.TAG {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #FF00FF;
  background: #FF99FF;
  color: #FF00FF;
  width: 60px;
  height: 17px;
  float:left;
  padding: 1px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #555;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 3px;
}

.icon_suppr {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  position:relative; top:0px; left:35px;
}

<div class="TAG">
  ERIC
  <img src="close-icon.png" class="icon_suppr"/>
</div>
```

Any idea ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the child to `position: absolute` and the parent to `position: relative`.

[**Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/jnopn1tL/5/)

In the example above I made the `div` a bit larger for demonstration only. It will always be `top:0` and `left: 35px` of the parent div.

```css
div.TAG {
  position: relative;      /* <---- added */
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #FF00FF;
  background: #FF99FF;
  color: #FF00FF;
  width: 60px;
  /* Evite que texte dépasse de la div */
  height: 17px;
  float: left;
  padding: 1px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #555;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 3px;
}

.icon_suppr {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  position: absolute;      /* <---- added */
  top: 0px;
  left: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="TAG">
  ERIC
  <img src="close-icon.png" class="icon_suppr" />
</div>
```

Comment: @Erixx Glad I could help! :) Please consider marking the answer as accepted, if it helped you.

Comment: please update your answer, position relative for the parent and absolute for the child.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<img>` is relatively positioned which means it will take it's position based on what the elements before it are doing. To absolutely position the image you need to add position: absolute to your `icon_suppr` class

```
.icon_suppr {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  position:absolute; top:0px; left:35px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set image inside another div absolutely, you should add relative/absolute/fixed position to it's parent

```
div.TAG {
        border-radius: 3px;
        border: 1px solid #FF00FF;
        background: #FF99FF;
        color: #FF00FF;
        width: 60px; /* Evite que texte dépasse de la div */
        height: 17px;
        float:left;
        padding: 1px;
        box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #555;
        z-index: 1;
        margin: 3px;
      position:relative;
    }

    .icon_suppr {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 12px;
        width: 12px;
        position:absolute; top:0px; left:35px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: relative` to `.TAG`, but `position: absolute` to `.icon_suppr`

[Result](https://jsfiddle.net/jnopn1tL/2/)